# Creating my own token on Solana Blockchain in 2023

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli

I created and minted my personal token on solana, but it has no name. The repository on github is closed and I don't understand how to verify my token at all. Tell me please.
Here is my ready-made token: https://solscan.io/token/51AUUVqApsPwW828MXAEqGTp4iZ52D2FbjL5rMgsYfmK#metadata
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If you're looking for a non technical person friendly tool to create a new token with proper metadata standard you can try this application.
https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/token-tools/create-token

Answer (score 2):

Here are good tutorials on getting started with Tokens (Fungible and Non-Fungible on Solana)

1. https://www.soldev.app/course/token-program (*fungible*)
2. https://calyptus.co/courses/2-creating-your-first-token/ (*fungible*)
3. https://jimii.pages.dev/mint-solana-anchor/ (*non-fungible*)

code example can be found here. https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can register your token using metaplex token-meta-data.
Now, Solana Github is not accepting PR for adding tokenInfo.
you can check out this url for adding token data

https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/token-standard

you can use this npm for adding your token metadata.

https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html

**Method Name:** createCreateMetadataAccountInstruction

once it is done, solscan will fetch your token details automatically.

Comment: Hello! I'm a Python developer by a big chance and I don't really understand js/ts. could you send some guides on token-metadata or contact me in telegram and help with solving this issue? My telegram: @nikodim54 Thank you again.