# If I use a solana token generator am I able to see the code of the token if I need to make changes

Tags: token

I want to create a solana token using a token generator but I want a copy of the code that is used to make it. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating my own token on Solana Blockchain in 2023](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/creating-my-own-token-on-solana-blockchain-in-2023)

Comment: If not, you're going to need to be more specific regarding what token generator you're using.

Answer (score 0):

it is very unlinkely that you can get the source code, except if it's open sourced. What changes do you want to make ?